# Mistakenly Installed gnome shell extension and tweak tools on Ubuntu 16.04(GUI Unity)

Tags: 16.04, gnome-shell-extension

Hi Guyzz,
I'm new to Ubuntu and was searching for additional software's that can be installed on Ubuntu.
Found Gnome shell extension :
Installed gnome shell extension and tweak tools using

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extension 
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tools
```

Was able to open tweak tools but extension tab was not visible.
 On searching more first found out workaround's
1.Restarting gnome shell using (ALT+F2 THAN typeing 'r') : still was facing issue.
2.Further searching found out gnome extension should be installed on gnome env and not on UNITY.

I'm having Unity GUI as at the top left I'm having UNITY symbol.
Is there any workaround or should I uninstall both packages using

```
sudo apt-get uninstall --auto-remove gnome-shell-extension 
sudo apt-get uninstall --auto-remove gnome-tweak-tools
```

If I uninstall both packages it will break the OS as was reading further that UNITY is build on Gnome.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

These aren't necessary components, if you don't need them or they aren't working for you, you can uninstall them.

Comment: Thanks for answering, Just had a query do they officially meant to work on UNITY.